# The life counter in my hangman work is not going down

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean runAgain = true;
        
        System.out.println("Starting game...\n\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Simple Hangman! You have six lives, so be wise with your guesses.");
        while(runAgain)
        {
            String secretWord = "";
            char[] secretWordArray = new char[8];
            char[] ansArray = new char[8]; 
            int lives = 6;
            int randNum = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
            if(randNum == 1)
            {
                secretWordArray[0] = 'd';
                secretWordArray[1] = 'i';
                secretWordArray[2] = 'n';
                secretWordArray[3] = 'o';
                secretWordArray[4] = 's';
                secretWordArray[5] = 'a';
                secretWordArray[6] = 'u';
                secretWordArray[7] = 'r';
                secretWord = "dinosaur";
            }
            if(randNum == 2)
            {
                secretWordArray[0] = 'c';
                secretWordArray[1] = 'o';
                secretWordArray[2] = 'm';
                secretWordArray[3] = 'p';
                secretWordArray[4] = 'u';
                secretWordArray[5] = 't';
                secretWordArray[6] = 'e';
                secretWordArray[7] = 'r';
                secretWord = "computer";
            }
            
            if(randNum == 3)
            {
                secretWordArray[0] = 's';
                secretWordArray[1] = 'o';
                secretWordArray[2] = 'f';
                secretWordArray[3] = 't';
                secretWordArray[4] = 'w';
                secretWordArray[5] = 'a';
                secretWordArray[6] = 'r';
                secretWordArray[7] = 'e';
                secretWord = "software";
            }
            
            if(randNum == 4)
            {
                secretWordArray[0] = 'f';
                secretWordArray[1] = 'o';
                secretWordArray[2] = 'o';
                secretWordArray[3] = 't';
                secretWordArray[4] = 'b';
                secretWordArray[5] = 'a';
                secretWordArray[6] = 'l';
                secretWordArray[7] = 'l';
                secretWord = "football";
            }
                
            System.out.println("\nYour secret word is: ");
            for(int i = 0; i<secretWordArray.length; i++) 
            {
                ansArray[i] = '*'; //takes length of the secret word and prints it in '*'
            }
            
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ansArray).replace("[", "").replace("]", " ").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")); //.replace to make the array one word
            
            
            while(lives>0) //ends when user dies (lives = 0)
            {
                getGuess(secretWordArray, ansArray, secretWord, lives);
                
                if(ansArray[0]==secretWordArray[0] && ansArray[1]==secretWordArray[1] && ansArray[2]==secretWordArray[2] && ansArray[3]==secretWordArray[3] && ansArray[4]==secretWordArray[4] && ansArray[5]==secretWordArray[5] && ansArray[6]==secretWordArray[6] && ansArray[7]==secretWordArray[7])
                {
                    System.out.println("\nYou won! Congratulations!\n\nWould you like to play again? Enter Yes or No:");
                    String wannaPlayAgain2 = in.nextLine();
                    if(wannaPlayAgain2.charAt(0)=='N' || wannaPlayAgain2.charAt(0)=='n')
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nThank you for playing.");
                        runAgain = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                //Death message & asks if you want to play again
                if(lives==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("You ran out of lives!\n\nWould you like to play again? Enter Yes or No");
                    String wannaPlayAgain = in.nextLine();
                    if(wannaPlayAgain.charAt(0)=='N' || wannaPlayAgain.charAt(0)=='n')
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!");
                        runAgain = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            } //end while (lives loop)
        } //end while(runAgain loop)
    } //end main
    
    public static void printGreeting()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting game...\n\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Simple Hangman! You have six lives, so be wise with your guesses.");
    }
 
    public static void getGuess(char[] secretWordArray, char[] ansArray, String secretWord, int lives) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n\nEnter your guess: ");
        String guessString = in.nextLine();
        char guess = guessString.charAt(0); 
        
        if(secretWord.contains(guessString)) //correct guess
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<secretWordArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if(secretWordArray[j] == guess)
                {
                    ansArray[j] = guess; //replaces the index in the filler array which has the users correct guess
                    System.out.println("The word contains the letter " + guess + "!");
                    System.out.println("Your word looks like this: " + Arrays.toString(ansArray).replace("[", "").replace("]", " ").replace(",", "").replace(" ", ""));
                    
                }
            } 
        }     
        else //incorrect guess
        { 
            lives--;
            System.out.println("The word does not contain the letter  " + guess + ".\nYou have " + lives + " lives left.");
            System.out.println("\nYour word looks like this: " + Arrays.toString(ansArray).replace("[", "").replace("]", " ").replace(",", "").replace(" ", ""));
        }
    }
    
} //end class
```

Working on a simple hangman game which picks a word randomly and gives the user 6 chances to guess it.

Everything else in my code is working as intended besides the lives loop. When the user guesses an incorrect answer, they're suppose to lose one life. The lives are stuck at 5 no matter what. Thank you in advance

Comment: Point out the line where you decrement the life counter.  That should be enough of a clue.  A spin in the debugger will show you why you aren't going into the else block.  Check your assumptions.

Comment: I thought I was going into the else block? It prints the different statement in the else block but it ignores lives--.

Comment: A debugger is your friend.  You're committing two classic new programmer mistakes: (1) Too much code, poorly decomposed, and (2) not doubting yourself enough.  Repeat after me: your code is wrong.  It's your job to figure out why.  Step through in a debugger and see where YOU went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the value of lives without returning or resetting it.  So, everytime your program runs `getGuess`, it is performing an action on the value of lives as if it were 6.  At no point does `getGuess` change the value of lives, so the lives is always 6 when it is passed to the method.

You can either move `lives` to a member variable, or have `getGuess` return a value to modify `lives`.

Comment: Your code isn't decomposed well.  All static methods is a bad idea.

Comment: agreed.  I initially started rewriting his code, but his question was why does lives not change.  I didn't want to go off track fixing other aspects of his code.  That being said, @b-rad90.  All of this code should be in a separate class, and instantiated in main().  Static methods shouldn't have any dependencies on external factors, so these methods shouldn't be static.  There are several other design issues with your code, but I'm happy to see you are coding and seeking help when you don't understand.  Good luck.

Comment: You were correct and gave an excellent answer.  Spot on.  I walked through it in a debugger and saw exactly the behavior that you cite.